# Problem Discord JS - Add role to message author

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I created a little code for a Halloween event. I have a little problem because I want to make sure that when he answers pong it gives him the Pong role and that the messages are deleted after 10s or in a short-lived fashion. Here is my code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [ 
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers 
    ] 
});

client.on("ready", () => { 
    console.log("I am ready!"); 
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => { 
    console.log(message) 
    if (message.author.bot) return 
    if (message.content === "ping") { 
        message.reply("pong!" ); 
    } 
});

client.login('MY TOKEN');
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What do you have problems with? The code above doesn't do anything you mentioned/required.

Answer (score 0):

You can add roles by doing:

```js
const roleTo = interaction.member

roleTo.roles.add(["roleid"])
```